# How to detect type of encryption?

Tags: encryption

I've been trying for a while to access the game information in Smite. That's how I can predict/know what will be released the next update. I have no harmful intentions. Just curious and it's fun.

Smite is created with Unreal Engine 3. In the Cooked folder there is a file called "TgGame.upk". That is where the game information is located.

To access it you have use an UPK Decompressor first and then you can use UE explorer. However it's encrypted and you can't use the UPK Decompressor. How can I detect what type of encryption it's?

Answer (score 3):

If they did the crypto right, by just looking at the ciphertext, you won't be able to tell what kind of encryption was used.

Since the software most likely has to decrypt these files, your best bet is to reverse engineer the software and figure it out from there.

Comment: The software dont actually decrypt any files. Every .upk file is compressed with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Oberhumer.
What UPK decompressor does is just decompressing the file. However since the file is encrypted the UPK decompressor dont work. I know a few people that have cracked the encryption but they dont want to share anything.

Comment: Is it ever decrypted?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the algorithm is only half of it; where do you plan to find the key, unless it's an easily broken cipher (rot13)?  If you have the key, the size might lend a clue.